# Easiest way to get count val from mysql in bash

Tags: mysql, bash

Maybe i should use python or perl but i dont know any.

I have 4 statements and i would like to check if there are any errors longer then an hour. My user is setup so i dont need to enter a mysql user/pass. This statement is in mysql_webapp_error_check.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql testdb -e "select count(*) from tbl where last_error_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1  HOUR);"
```

How do i make it give me the return value (count(*)) instead of printing to screen?

Then i'll write an if statement and output to stdout/err for cron to use to email me (otherwise i want the script to be silent so nothing is emailed unless theres a problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo show databases\; | mysql -u root | (while read x; do
  echo "$x"
  y="$x"
done
echo "$y"
)
```

Answer (score 11):

Searched the same, -s for silent works exactly for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
result=`mysql testdb -s -e "select count(*) from tbl where last_error_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1  HOUR);"`
echo result = .$result.
```

PS.: There is also a --batch parameter in my mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49 which "Write fields without conversion. Used with --batch" so its a little off-topic here, but should be  mentioned here.

Answer (score 5):

in bash, you use `$()` syntax.

```
#!/bin/bash
ret=$(mysql testdb -e "select count(*) from tbl where last_error_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1  HOUR);")
if [[ "$ret" > 0 ]];then
   echo "there is count"
else
   echo "no count"
fi
```

Comment: It doesnt work. It always says there is count. I tested with  -e "select 0;" and the actual command i'll be using. Both are 0 and reported nonzero

Comment: It works if you execute `| grep -v "count"` before getting the return value (in the original, the first line has the string `count` and the 2nd the value, tested with mysql 5.6).

Comment: @LucasBasquerotto `| grep -v "COUNT"`, it's case sensitive.

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau If you run `select count(*)` you use `| grep -v "count"`. If you run `select COUNT(*)` you use `| grep -v "COUNT"`. I personally use `COUNT`, but the answer above used `count`, so I commented related to it.

Comment: @LucasBasquerotto Ah, makes sense :-) anyone who is concerned could use `| grep -vi "count"` and it won't care about case

Answer (score 3):

I usually do this:

```
 var=`mysql -e "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...\G" | awk '/COUNT/{print $2}/'`
```

Answer (score 2):

For my part I simply use **`grep -v`** to exclude the line printing `count(*)` from the return of MySQL.

So I get the counter like that:

```
db_name="NAME_DB";
db_user="USER_DB";
db_pwd="PWD_DB";
counter=`mysql -u${db_user} -p${db_pwd} ${db_name} -e "SELECT count(*) FROM my_table WHERE something = '1';" | grep -v "count"`;
echo "Count for request: $counter";
```

I use it for some Wordpress stuff this way, reading databases infos from the `wp-config.php` file:

```
wp_db_infos="wp-config.php";
wp_db=`cat ${wp_db_infos} | grep "DB_NAME" | awk -F ', ' '{print $2}' | awk -F "'" '{print $2}'`;
wp_user=`cat ${wp_db_infos} | grep "DB_USER" | awk -F ', ' '{print $2}' | awk -F "'" '{print $2}'`;
wp_pwd=`cat ${wp_db_infos} | grep "DB_PASSWORD" | awk -F ', ' '{print $2}' | awk -F "'" '{print $2}'`;
img_to_update=`mysql -u${wp_user} -p${wp_pwd} ${wp_db} -e "SELECT count(*) FROM wp_offres WHERE maj_img = '1';" | grep -v "count"`;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
local count=$(mysql -u root --disable-column-names --batch --execute "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '$DstDbName'")
    if [[ "$count" > 0 ]]
    then
    fi
```

--batch   - do clear output w/o borders
--disable-column-names  - prints only row with value

no creasy AWK used :)